# How to adapt the height of an HTML widget to the height of the window in R Shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny

How to adapt it so that it can be correctly rendered on different screens?
(`height = "100%"` and `height = "auto"` don't work)

I have to add text that is not code
I have to add text that is not code
I have to add text that is not code
I have to add text that is not code
I have to add text that is not code

[EDIT] Reprex below

```
    RequiredLibraries <- c("data.table", "visNetwork", "shiny")

    RequiredLibraries2Install <- RequiredLibraries[!(RequiredLibraries %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]

    if(length(RequiredLibraries2Install))   install.packages(RequiredLibraries2Install, dependencies = TRUE)

    lapply(RequiredLibraries, library, character.only = TRUE)

    ui <- fluidPage(
        titlePanel(windowTitle = "Application Title", title = "Application Title"),
        
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                h4("Year End"),
                #hr(),
                selectInput(inputId = "YE", label = "Year End", choices = 2016:2020, selected = c(2018), multiple = FALSE, selectize = FALSE),
                width = 2
            ),
            mainPanel(
                # Freeze the main (on the right) panel and leave the sidebar (on the left) panel scrollable
                style = "position:fixed;left:17%;",
                tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                    tabPanel("Network",
                        visNetworkOutput(outputId = "Network", width = "100%", height = "75vh")
                    ),
                    tabPanel(actionLink(inputId = "Download.Network.Data", label = "Download current network data", icon = icon(name = "download", class = NULL, lib = "font-awesome"))
                    )
                ),
                width = 10
            )
        )
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session)
    {
        GenerateNetwork <- reactive({
            # Taken from https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/edges.html
            Links <- data.frame(from = sample(1:10, 8), to = sample(1:10, 8),
                    # add labels on edges
                    label = paste("Edge", 1:8),
                    # length
                    length = c(100, 500),
                    # width
                    width = c(4, 1),
                    # arrows
                    arrows = c("to", "from", "middle", "middle;to"),
                    # dashes
                    dashes = c(TRUE, FALSE),
                    # tooltip (html or character)
                    title = paste("Edge", 1:8),
                    # smooth
                    smooth = c(FALSE, TRUE),
                    # shadow
                    shadow = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
                )
            Nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:10, group = c("A", "B"))
            
            visNetwork(Nodes, Links, width = "100%", height = "700px", main = "Network Title") %>%
                    visInteraction(navigationButtons = TRUE, keyboard = TRUE) %>%
                    visPhysics(stabilization = TRUE) %>%
                    #visLegend(addNodes = Legend.Nodes, addEdges = Legend.Links, useGroups = FALSE, width = 0.25, position = "right", main = "Network Legend", ncol = 1) %>%
                    visLayout(randomSeed = 123)
        })
        # Create the output Network
        output$Network <- renderVisNetwork(GenerateNetwork())
    }

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS unit `vh`. E.g. `100vh`, that means 100% of the height of the viewport. You can also try `fit-content`.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this unit! Thanks a lot @Stéphane Laurent!
Actually, ideally, I would like that the height adapts automatically to the height available, which might not always be the total height of the screen/viewport. In my particular case the widget is within a `tabPanel`, itself within a `tabsetPanel`, itself within a `mainPanel`, itself within a `sidebarLayout`.

Comment: @Olivier7121 Not sure, but maybe `height = "fit-content"`. But I believe this option is not possible with HTML widgets... (however this is a valid CSS value). What is your widget by the way?

Comment: Yes, `height = "fit-content"` works perfectly, thanks a lot, @Stéphane Laurent!
I use a widget from the `visNetwork` package (and the function is `visNetworkOutput`).

Comment: @Olivier7121 Ok, then I edited my answer. Could you accept it please?

Comment: My apologies, I was fooled from a cached value... The option `height = "fit-content"` doesn't work: for some reason the R Shiny application I ran was executed with previous (valid and with the desired effect, but 'manual') values of this option (there was an error but the application was still able to execute, strange...).
The error I get is: `Error in htmltools::validateCssUnit(height) : 
  "fit-content" is not a valid CSS unit (e.g., "100%", "400px", "auto")`
I realised that when I ran the application on another machine.
@Moderators: don't know how to cancel my acceptation of the answer?

Comment: @Olivier7121 That's what I thought. Could you post a minimized version of your app? We need another way to set this CSS property.

Comment: @Olivier7121 FYI, I opened a new [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/issues/189).

Comment: I just posted a reprex in my original post, @Stéphane Laurent. Thanks for having opened a new issue on the github of `htmltools`.

Comment: @Olivier7121 You can install the development version of `htmltools` (from Github), it now allows `fit-content`.

Comment: That was quick, thanks @Stéphane Laurent! Unfortunately I have issues installing `htmltools` from Github. `ERROR: failed to lock directory 'C:/Users/Olivier/Documents/R/win-library/4.0' for modifying
Try removing 'C:/Users/Olivier/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/00LOCK-htmltools'
Erreur : Failed to install 'htmltools' from GitHub:
  (converti depuis l'avis) installation of package ‘C:/Users/Olivier/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCIp9Hb/file261c11d94901/htmltools_0.5.0.9002.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: I will wait for an official release of `htmltools` on CRAN then.

Comment: Update 08.05.2022: I just used the last version to date of `htmltools` (0.5.2). I don't have errors anymore but the height of the widget is absolutely not adapted to the height of the screen (instead the widget is very small).
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: `height = "fit-content"` doesn't work.

Comment: @Olivier7121 `100vh` is the full height of the screen. What do you mean by `fit-content` doesn't work?

Comment: I mean `fit-content` doesn't fit the content to the size of the screen.